# Trying to incorporate sound within a beacon region in Swift

Tags: audio, beacon, unresolved-external

I am getting "Use of unresolved identifier 'player' in my code using beacons and regions. For this particular region, I also want it to play a sound (Siren.wav). Code is below:

```
import Combine
import CoreLocation
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

class BeaconDetector: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var objectWillChange =  ObservableObjectPublisher()
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    var lastDistance = CLProximity.unknown
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    //   var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


    override init() {
        super.init()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self) {
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
               startScanning()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func startScanning() {
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")!
        let constraint = CLBeaconIdentityConstraint(uuid: uuid)
        let beaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(beaconIdentityConstraint: constraint, identifier: "MyBeacon")

        locationManager?.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
        locationManager?.startRangingBeacons(satisfying: constraint)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRange beacons: [CLBeacon], satisfying beaconConstraint: CLBeaconIdentityConstraint) {
        if let beacon = beacons.first {
            update(distance: beacon.proximity)
        } else {
            update(distance: .unknown)
        }
    }

    func update(distance: CLProximity) {
        lastDistance = distance
        self.objectWillChange.send()
    }
}

struct BigText: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
                   .font(Font.system(size: 72, design: .rounded))
         .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var detector = BeaconDetector()

    var body: some View {
        if detector.lastDistance == .immediate {
            return Text("DANGER TOO CLOSE")
            .modifier(BigText())
                .background(Color.red)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            func playSound() {
                guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Siren", withExtension: "wav") else { return }
                do {
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

                    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.wav.rawValue)
                    guard let player = player else { return }

                    player.play()

                }
                catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an "unresolved identifier" error is because the variable `player` is not defined in the `playSound()` method.  In the Swift language, each variable declaration has a specific "scope" and they cannot be accessed outside that scope.

In this case, `player` is defined as a member variable in the  `BeaconDetector` class.  Because the `playSound()` method is not in the same variable "scope", you get that error when you try to access the variable.

You might want to read [this tutorial](https://learnappmaking.com/scope-context-swift-how-to/) on how variable scope works in Swift.